# Google App Script oAuth2 to Questrade API Invalid Token

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to used Google Apps Script to pull Questrade account information into a Google sheets spreadsheet.  I've added the oAuth2 library from GitHub(https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) then mostly copy and pasted (with minor edits) from the example code.

The weird thing is this code has worked, exactly how it is, but a day later it no longer works and returns the following:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://api01.iq.questrade.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"code":1017,"message":"Access token is invalid"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

My Google Apps Script is posted below.  I've only removed my Questrade **Client_ID** and Google Script **Script_ID**.  I have three buttons in my spreadsheet which I've linked to functions in the script:

Button 1 - **QT oAuth** - calls showSidebar

Button 2 - **Load Account Info** - calls makeRequest

Button 3 - **QT Logout** - calls logout

Typically, I press the **QT Logout** button to reset 0Auth2 services then I press the **QT oAuth** button.  This seems to successfully go through the authorization process. I then press the **Load Account Info** button and about 99 times out of 100 I get the invalid access token message.  *I don't know if it's relevant, but when I log into Questrades API hub I can see that the script is adding an authorization after the QT oAuth button is pressed but it seems to disappear after about a minute.*

The script:

```
function getQTService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('QT')

      // Set the endpoint URLs.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret.
      .setClientId('Client_ID')
      .setClientSecret(' ')   //there is no client secret but oAuth2 requires one

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties()) 
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      
      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      .setScope('read_acc')
            
}

function showSidebar() {
  var QTService = getQTService();
  if (!QTService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = QTService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  } else {
  // ...
  }
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var QTService = getQTService();
  var isAuthorized = QTService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
     return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
    
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}



function makeRequest() {
  var QTService = getQTService();
  var token = QTService.getAccessToken();
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Script_ID");
  // Get account number
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts',{
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var accountdata = JSON.parse(json);

  var j = 0;

  while(j < accountdata.accounts.length) {
    var Account_num = accountdata.accounts[j].number;
    var Account_type = accountdata.accounts[j].type;

    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(Account_type);

    // GET CASH BALANCE
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts/' + Account_num + '/balances',{
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });
  
    json = response.getContentText();
    var balancedata = JSON.parse(json);
  
    var i = 0;
    while(balancedata.perCurrencyBalances[i].currency != 'CAD') {
      i=i+1;
    }

    //send cash value to spreadsheet
    sheet.getRange("G1").setValue(balancedata.perCurrencyBalances[i].cash);

    // GET POSITIONS
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts/' + Account_num + '/positions',{
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });
  
    json = response.getContentText();
    var positionsdata = JSON.parse(json);
  
    var num_of_positions = positionsdata.positions.length;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < num_of_positions) {  //this loop is not that smart assumes the positions are where I specify, fix later
    
      if(positionsdata.positions[i].symbol == 'VCN.TO'){ 
        sheet.getRange("D5").setValue(positionsdata.positions[i].openQuantity);
      }
      if(positionsdata.positions[i].symbol == 'VUN.TO') {
        sheet.getRange("D6").setValue(positionsdata.positions[i].openQuantity);
      }
      if(positionsdata.positions[i].symbol == 'VIU.TO') {
        sheet.getRange("D7").setValue(positionsdata.positions[i].openQuantity);
      }
      if(positionsdata.positions[i].symbol == 'VEE.TO') {
        sheet.getRange("D8").setValue(positionsdata.positions[i].openQuantity);
      }
      i=i+1;
    }
    j=j+1;
  }
  //send cash value to spreadsheet
 //   sheet.getRange("G1").setValue(data.perCurrencyBalances[i].cash);
  

 
}

function logout() {
  var service = getQTService();
  service.reset();
}
```

Any advice on what might be going wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rely on using api01.  I think you have to extract the api_server from the auth call that gives you a token (or at least I did this using the example on https://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/getting-started with refresh_token).  My last 3 refresh_token auths for a bearer have yielded the api06 endpoint.  I took your code and with the oauth authorizing and using api06 it works fine.

The magic sauce is `var api_server = QTService.getToken().api_server;`

Comment: Thanks so much your "magic sauce" seems to have done the trick. I'm afraid I don't understand how api01 differs from api06 and can't seem to find a definition in Questrade's documentation but the code works now.

Comment: Questrade has multiple API servers that respond to API calls.  In this case, when you auth and receive a token, it only authorizes you on one of their servers.  In most cases, you would just have a static endpoint e.g. api.example.com, but they are probably doing some sort of rudimentary load balancing and that's why they tell you what server to talk to.

Comment: You may also want to add `.setRefreshUrl('https://login.questrade.com/oauth2/token')` on the createService call, and copy/use withRetry from https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/27c61fcc15af19f9d6505d2a6170ff883f0bd868/samples/Salesforce.gs, which will refresh your token if it expires (you need to have it search for 'Access token is invalid' instead of 'INVALID_SESSION_ID').  Thanks for sharing your example code, it was a great starting point for me!

Comment: Ah okay, now it makes sense why the original code occasionally worked (i.e. when the API server handling my request just happened to be api01).  I'll look into the token refresh. 
 Thanks again for your help.